# WebRTC Compatiblity between chrome android and chrome desktop

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, google-chrome, webrtc

As the title says, is the communication (encoding & decoding) between chrome android and chrome deskstop are fully working ?

I'm assuming, both chrome versions are 64+ and support `getUserMedia`, `RTCPeerConnection` and `RTCDataChannel`

Based on [this project](https://github.com/lucaslouca/video-conference-webrtc), I have tested the following.

Audio/video host/receivers are working on :

- Chrome Desktop <> Chrome Deskstop
- Firefox Desktop <> Chrome Deskstop

But it's not working with :

- Chrome Desktop <> Chrome Android
- Chrome Android <> Chrome Desktop
- Chrome Android <> Chrome Android

For information, I tested on Honor 7 Android version 6.0

So I wanted to know, is anyone was able to send/receive WebRTC between a chrome android browser and a chrome desktop browser ?
The goal of my project is to create a web videoconference based on WebRTC, with chrome android and chrome desktop users.

Comment: Could this be a networking problem?